# ".use" method to add logic on each request of SuperAgent

Tags: node.js, request, logic, superagent

This [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/384) in SuperAgent repository mentions the `.use` method to add logic on each request. For example, adding an `Authorization` header for JWT when a token is available:

```
superagent.use( bearer );

function bearer ( request ) {
    var token = sessionStorage.get( 'token' );

    if ( token ) request.set( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token );
}
```

Although the last comment informs that this feature is working again, I can't make it to work.

The following test code:

```
var request = require( 'superagent' );

request.use( bearer );

function bearer ( request )
{
    // "config" is a global var where token and other stuff resides
    if ( config.token ) request.set( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + config.token );
}
```

Returns this error:

```
request.use( bearer );
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: Please, explain the reasons why you downvoted the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: the `request` function that is exported by superagent does not have a `use` method. however, the instance of `Request` that is returned by executing `request` does. Whether or not this is a bug, or can be fixed without a pull request is unclear.

Comment: In other words, the error you are getting is expected, based on looking at the source. The readme also does not show an example of your useage, so it(your usecase) may not be an intended useage.

Comment: Per your comment, yeah, i don't get that popup and don't feel an explanation is needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue you linked to isn't linked to any commits, so all we can do is speculate on whether or not that feature was implemented and then removed, or never implemented in the first place.

If you [read through the src](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/2705a089735524e345f0f85391146587425d8f54/lib/client.js#L504), you will see that `use` is only ever defined on the prototype of the `Request` constructor, meaning it can only ever be used after you've began constructing a request, [as shown in the readme](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#plugins).

In other words, the issue seems to be talking about a feature that either has been removed, or never existed. You should instead use the syntax mentioned in the readme.

```
var request = require('superagent');

request
.get('/some-url')
.use(bearer) // affects **only** this request
.end(function(err, res){
    // Do something
});

function bearer ( request ){
    // "config" is a global var where token and other stuff resides
    if ( config.token ) {
        request.set( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + config.token );
    }
}
```

You could of course create your own wrapper so that you don't have to do it for every request.

```
var superagent = require('superagent');

function request(method, url) {
    // callback
    if ('function' == typeof url) {
        return new superagent.Request('GET', method).end(url).use(bearer);
    }

    // url first
    if (1 == arguments.length) {
        return new superagent.Request('GET', method).use(bearer);
    }

    return new superagent.Request(method, url).use(bearer);
} 
// re-implement the .get and .post helpers if you feel they're important..

function bearer ( request ){
    // "config" is a global var where token and other stuff resides
    if ( config.token ) {
        request.set( 'Authorization', 'Bearer ' + config.token );
    }
}

request('GET', '/some-url')
.end(function(err, res){
    // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently the package [superagent-use](https://github.com/koenpunt/superagent-use) has been released to facilitate setting use globally for superagent requests.